# How to migrate my eclipse to another computer?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

How can I migrate my eclipse and plugins from my computer to my laptop?
My eclipse has an ADT and Android plugins and I dunno if it works to copy only the eclipse folder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just copy the eclipse folder. But some configurations will get lost because they are made per workspace. So you might also want to copy a workspace.

Answer (score 1):

Copying the Eclipse folder should work. Try it.

Having said that, when I'm in the same situation I usually just do a reinstall of Eclipse - it doesn't take long assuming you have a fast network connection and it's a good opportunity to get a clean install with all the latest plugin versions.